# jquery replace issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-click-event

I have series of divs, that represent similar to a chess board. but this is a kinda tricky chess. basically users clicks on a piece, and clicks on enemy piece. if it can kill. it should  move it to the enemies position. And enemy should be deleted.

```
<div class="column" data-square="4-4">
<div class="white-king lol">a</div>
</div>
<div class="column" data-square="4-5">
<div class="black-pawn lol">b</div>
</div>
<div class="column" data-square="4-6">
<div class="blue lol">c</div>
</div>
```

//so when users first clicks on whiteking, we get the data-square, assign it to a variable $from, then clicks on enemy black-pawn. does some validation in server, and should move the

​
  inner div of square = 4-4 to inner div of square = 4-5  , the inner div of square = 4-5 should be deleted and the inner div of square= 4-4 should be presnet

I have tried using jquery clone. but it doesnt works out well
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jm4eb/13/

Comment: I wouldn't even both with `.clone`. Just work within the contents and classes. e.g. assuming "a" is moving to "b": `$to.addClass('white-king').text($from.text())` then `$from.removeClass('white-king').text('')`

Comment: don't use an extra div to insert the cloned element.. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/jm4eb/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally wouldn't get too bent out of shape replacing one element with another. I'd look at just swapping the attributes from one element to another. Remove the `white-king` class from one element and add it to another.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I will look into how to do it. And it sounds to me most clever solution

Comment: If I could vote up, trust me i wont stop voting! you are a true programmer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the good way still, but you can try

```
(function() {

        var from = null;
          var $change =null;
        var to = null;

        $(".column" ).click(function(){
            if(from === null)
            {
                $(this).css("background-color","yellow");

                from = $(this).data('square');
                    $change= ($('<div/>').append($(this).clone(true).children()).html());


            }
            else
            {

                to = $(this).data('square');
                $(this).html("").html($change);
                $('div[data-square="'+from+'"]').html("<div class=lol>empty</div>").css("background-color","");
                from = to = null;
            }
        });

    }());​
```